# Basketball Earth

Tags: knowledge, visual, pattern, geography, sports

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

Below, you will see a map with twenty UN members or observer states labelled with one or more letters from A-G (except one, which is labelled 'X'). Additionally, seven images of basketballs are presented, numbered 1-7.

> **TASK: Deduce the map labelling rule that enables you to pair up each letter A-G with exactly one number 1-7. Additionally, explain with justification which letter(s) should take the place of the black 'X' near the centre of the map.**

[image: World map with labelled countries, and seven numbered basketball images]

(Click image to enlarge)

<sup>*For avoidance of doubt, the labelled countries on this map are (in alphabetical order): Democratic Republic of the Congo, Estonia, eSwatini, Ethiopia, Guinea-Bissau, Liechtenstein, Netherlands, North Korea, North Macedonia, Palestine, Saint Kitts and Nevis, Saint Vincent and the Grenadines, São Tomé and Príncipe, South Korea, South Sudan, Switzerland, Turkmenistan, United Arab Emirates, United States, and Uzbekistan.*</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the X should be replaced by

> D

First off

> The seven images at the bottom are all a part of the logo of a different NBA basketball team. Namely (in order)
>
> ```
> Brooklyn Nets
> Indiana Pacers
> Miami Heat
> Oklahoma City Thunder
> Orlando Magic
> Phoenix Suns
> Washington Wizards
> ```

The mapping rule:

> Each state gets assigned those basketball teams which names (excluding the city) can be made using the letters of the state. E.g. for "Switzerland (EG)", we can make "wizards" and "nets", but not any of the others. In the end this gives us the following map:
>
> ```
> A = Miami Heat
> B = Indiana Pacers
> C = Oklahoma City Thunder
> D = Phoenix Suns
> E = Brooklyn Nets
> F = Orlando Magic
> G = Washington Wizards
> ```

So the X

> must be "D", as only "Suns" can be made out of "South Sudan"

Comment: Indeed, this is the correct solution :) You've made an unspoken deduction in your first step though, which might be useful for some users to have explicit in the answer, namely rot13(gur 'vzntrf bs onfxrgonyyf' ner cnegf bs gur ybtbf bs AON grnzf - fbzrguvat V qryvorengryl arire npghnyyl fcryyrq bhg va gur chmmyr frg-hc... Lbh'ir whfg whzcrq fgenvtug gb 'Gur frira onfxrgonyy grnzf ner...' juvpu zvtug yrnir n srj crbcyr guvaxvat 'Jurer qvq gung pbzr sebz??')

Comment: Thanks for adding that clarification, the checkmark is yours :) In fact, on consulting the two lists required when making this question, these are the *only* such examples when using simple country names. I got totally lucky that all of the required logos actually featured basketballs!